# ArcGIS - Coordinate System Issue

Tags: gis, arcgis

I'm having issue in **Coordinate System**.

Originally, My Coordinate System is set as:

[Picture 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvls2.jpg)

When I add a shape file, I receive following error

[Picture 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FW4Q.jpg)

Upon Clicking Transformations, Following Screen comes:

[Picture 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfvtC.jpg)

**Upon Click OK, Still:**

> ArcMap Screen still remains Blank

as Follows:

[Picture 04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPZbi.jpg)

Let me know how to resolve this Issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use

> Data Frame Properties

to Resolve your Issue of Coordinate System as Mentioned inside the `Screenshots`